# Filter and copy all the subdirectories and its content

Tags: linux, filter, find, rsync

I have a list of directories and files that I need to migrate. The directory tree looks something like:

```
-var
   -data
      -archive
           -111111
               -logs
                  datetime.log 
               meter.txt
           -222222
               -logs
                  datetime.log 
               meter.txt
           -configurations
               -rules
               config.json
           -recycle
```

When copying, it should satisfy the below conditions:

- Copy only files/ directories that are less than or equal to 30 days. (This condition is not applicable to the `configurations` directory. Get all contents under configuration irrespective of its creation/modification date time.)
- Exclude the directory `recycle`.
- Copy only the content under `archive`. That means do not copy directories `var`, `data` & `archive.`

After copying the directory should look something like this:

```
-target
     -111111
          -logs
              datetime.log 
           meter.txt
     -222222
          -logs
              datetime.log 
          meter.txt
     -configurations
          -rules
          config.json
```

I came up with this:

```bash
find var/data/archive ! -path "*/recycle*" \( -path "*/configurations*" -o -name "*"  -mtime -30 \) | rsync -av --inplace --files-from=- . target
```

I am able to achieve the first 2 conditions, i.e. copying files that are less than 30 days and excluding the directory `recycle`. But not able to exclude `var/data/archive`. How do I fix this?

Comment: `--mindepth 2`?

Comment: @tripleee If I execute the find command separately, it's returning me the expected response.  But, when that response reaches Rsync, the root directories (var/data/archive) gets created. Can't we avoid Rsync from creating these folders? If it's not possible in Rsync, then what about 'CPIO'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```bash
cd ${HOME}/var/data/archive;\ 
find . ! -path "*/recycle*" \( -path "*/configurations*" -o -name "*"  -mtime -10 \) | rsync -av --inplace --files-from=- . ${HOME}/target
```